# Matrices representing a map between free modules of infinite rank and Fitting's Lemma (Eisenbud)

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

p.497 of *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, Eisenbud:

> If $\phi: F \rightarrow G$ is a map of free modules, then $I_j\phi$ is the image of the map
>
> $$\Lambda^j F \otimes \Lambda^j G^* \rightarrow R$$
>
> induced by $\Lambda^j \phi: \Lambda^j F \rightarrow \Lambda^j G$. If we choose bases for $F$ and $G$, then $\phi$ may be represented by a matrix, and we see that $I_j\phi$ is generated by the minors (that is, determinants of submatrices) of size $j$ of that matrix. We make the convention that the determinant of the $0 \times 0$ matrix (like a product with no factors) is $1$. In particular, $I_0\phi = R$, and more generally, we set $I_j\phi = R$ if $j\leq 0.$

**Question 1**

How is the matrix defined if F and G are of infinite rank? How are the $j \times j$ submatrices defined?

**Question 2**

Just after giving this definition, the author proves Fitting's Lemma,

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a ring $R$, and let $\phi: F \rightarrow G \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ and $\phi': F' \rightarrow G' \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ be two presentations, with $G$ and $G'$ finitely generated free modules of ranks $r$ and $r'$. For each number $i$ with $0 \leq i < \infty$, we have $I_{r-i}(\phi) = I_{r'-i}(\phi')$, and we define the ith Fitting invariant of $M$ to be the ideal $$Fitt_i(M) = I_{r-i}\phi \subset R.$$

The author only proves the case when $F$ and $F'$ are finitely generated and says the case for an infinite rank follows from that. Why is that true? He gives a hint saying we can write $\phi$ as "a linear combination of the appropriate minors of $\phi'$ by restricting to a ring finitely generated over $\Bbb{Z}$, and to finitely generated free modules mapping to $F$ and $F'$." Again, he is talking about the minors of $\phi$ and $\phi'$, both of which are assumed to be infinite matrices?

Comment: If there is no convention somewhere in the book, then instead of $\Lambda^j G^*$ should be $(\Lambda^j G)^*$. Then I think you can figure out how is defined the map $\Lambda^j F \otimes (\Lambda^j G)^* \rightarrow R$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you, but then why does he talk about minors of $\phi$ when he specifically says that it is *not* finitely generated (and hence of infinite rank) (see my second question).

Comment: I don't know and I don't see how is this useful, as one can always reduces to the finite case.